# Jobs are getting submitted in child queue but not in parent queue

Tags: hadoop, resources, threadpool, hadoop-yarn

I created a subpool in resource pool configuration in cloudera.
Earlier the parent queue of that subpool was working fine but after creating a single subpool under a parent pool gives an error while submitting Hadoop job that application can't be submitted as the queue is not a leaf queue.

Now, we have deleted the subpool of that queue and now still we are getting the same error. Earlier the parent queue was working very fine but now after addition and then deletion of subpool under that parent pool am getting the same error.

root.arb is not a leaf queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure on cloudera distribution. But as YARN, core concept is that you can not submit job to a queue which has child. As you said even after removing child , you are getting the same error. Usually in Apache Hadoop, a restart is required when a queue configuration is deleted. But adding queue can be managed by just `yarn rmadmin -refreshQueues`, in cloudera you might have some tab to refresh the same if required.
Other wise a simple YARN restart might help you.

Comment: Hi Ajay,

Thanks for the solution. It's very helpful. :)